# input text name array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, input

I have a form that uses jquery to generate rows of input fields
these text inputs need to be tied into and array 1,2,3... with the sub array designating the value for a,b,c,d..

```
       <td><input type="text" name="1[a]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="1[b]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="1[c]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="1[d]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="1[e]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="1[f]"/></td>
```

This is what i am getting

```
print_r($_POST);
```

> ```
> Array ( [1] => S [1a] => 6 [1b] => 5 [1c] => 4 [1d] => 3 [1e] => 2 [2] => M [2a] => 6 [2b] => 5 [2c] => 4 [2d] => 3 [2e] => 2 )
> ```

I Want:
1 as the array and a,b,c,d... as the sub array with value

1[a]=value
1[b]=value

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You'll have to do something more complex than just assigning a name. You can't do this without manipulating the data before submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP you cannot have variable names starting with numbers, so call it "one" an it will work.

Comment: I am an idiot. The code i posted works. i just had not uploaded the revision as seen, I had uploaded name="1a" instead of "1[a]"